# Only use one column of 2D array java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I have a 2D String array freq: 
`String freq[][] = new String[26][2];`
and I would like to use the contents of the first column only with `new String(freq)` which would work if freq is a normal array. However I would like to do this with the first column of my 2D array, or would I have to use two 1D arrays to do this:

```
String freq[][] = new String[26][2];
    int free = 0;
    for (int b = 0; b < words.length; b++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < words[b][0].length(); l++) {
            if (new String(freq[0]).indexOf(words[b][0].charAt(l)) < 0) {
                freq[free][0] = Character.toString(words[b][0].charAt(l));
                free++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want. Do you want a new `String` instance which contains all of the value in the first column concatenated together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder` and concat all the values (replace 8 with whatever your average word length is):

```
final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(words.length * 8);
for (String[] nestedWords : words)
{
    builder.append(nestedWords[0]);
}

return builder.toString();
```

You could also do this in java 8 as so:

```
return Arrays.stream(words).map(a -> a[0]).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quiet sure if I understand what you want to achive but if you only want to iterate over the first column just do something like this and just drop the inner loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  //Do stuff with words[i][0], e.g.
  words[i][0] = Some_usefull_thing;
}
```

Comment: Not quite, I want all the values of the first column into a new String instance